# Which is the best way to use angular ng-app?

Tags: angularjs, ng-app

I am new to angular. Shoud I use the same ng-app throughout the site or should I use different ng-app directives for different pages?

Answer (score 0):

Use one app for your app, and use different controllers for each page.
So put ng-app in html-tag.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">....
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a good framework for [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) so you should use just one declaration of "ng-app" inside a single page and load Partial Views with other directives such as "ng-include", "ng-view", "ui-view", etc... for portions of html inside the body tag with one controller per each of these.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your help.  Also Want to know does it matter that if I use ng-app or I use id="myApp" and then bootstrap this app ??